# why the list is not appending the correct tuple? its appending strang values, the first value of tuple appended is 0 or1

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I am trying to get all edges from an adjecency matrix. Here is the code and matrix:

```
adjeceny_matrix=np.zeros(shape=(count,count))


for i in range(len(df_for_author_citation)):
    z=df_for_author_citation.loc[i]["author_id"]
    for k in df_for_author_citation.loc[i]["Reference_authors_used_by_81_authors"]:
        adjeceny_matrix[i][all_authors[k]]+=1
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
array([[29.,  5.,  7., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [10., 21., 11., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 9.,  3., 21., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   ...,
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

Now, when I am trying to get edges such that :

```
edges=[]

weight=[]
for i in range(adjeceny_matrix.shape[0]):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(adjeceny_matrix.shape[1]):
        if adjeceny_matrix[i][j]==0:
            continue
        elif adjeceny_matrix[i][j]>0:
            print(i,j,adjeceny_matrix[i,j])
            edges.append(tuple([i,j]))
```

to my surprise, the edges is coming like this:

```
 (0, 493),

 (0, 756),
 (0, 757),
 (0, 758),
 (0, 759),
 (0, 760),
 (0, 740),
 (0, 741),
 (0, 742),
 (0, 743),
 (0, 744),
 (0, 745),
 (0, 746),

 .
 .
 .
 .
 (1, 146),
 (1, 147),
 (1, 170),
 (1, 171),
 (1, 175),
 (1, 176),

 (1, 959),
 (1, 960),
 (1, 961),
 (1, 962),
 ...]
```

In other words, the tuples that got appended are not the correct ones and their first elements only contain either 0 or 1

But there are clearly other set of vertcies too, where value of matrix is greater than 0 .

```
for example:

21 1664 1.0
21 1834 1.0
21 2771 2.0
21 2874 1.0
21 3279 1.0
21 3475 1.0
21 3643 2.0
21 3644 1.0
21 3645 1.0
21 3646 1.0
21 3647 1.0
21 3648 1.0
21 3649 2.0
21 3650 1.0
```

please tell me how to append the edges based on adjeceny_matrix[i][j]>0 critera

Comment: Please post an MCVE. We don't need to see a sample of your full matrix, which we can't reproduce. You need to construct a small, shareable, matrix that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't `adjeceny_matrix[i][j]` be `adjeceny_matrix[i,j]`?

Comment: no, this one is for directed grapgh, so only top 81 grapgh nodes will have edges from them,